# How to stream video FROM Glass?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, google-glass

I'm trying to bring an Android application to Glass, one which lets the user stream video from their camera. Whenever I try to actually start the streaming, however, I get an error back from the MediaRecorder saying, "start failed: -12". Unfortunately there's not a lot of information about that error on Android, and even less on Glass. Any help?

Comment: Any code? How are you streaming? Is this local or remotely?

Comment: Have you found a slotution to your problem? I am having the "start failed: -19" error code on Glass.

Comment: See http://www.meetup.com/gdgaustin/events/175957142/: people successfully run WebRTC on Glass.

Answer (score 1):

I found nice example with libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) there:
[Google Glass stream video to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223277/google-glass-stream-video-to-server)

You could try it on your phone first. 
I tried simple RTSP server(example 1) as well as streaming through Wowza server, which adds some delay.