# Google glass video stream

Tags: video, stream, google-glass, google-gdk, aero-glass

I'm trying to create an app for Glass to stream video using GDK.
I found nice example with libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) there:
[Google Glass stream video to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223277/google-glass-stream-video-to-server)

The solution there creates stream server on the phone. VLC might be used to connect to it. If receive buffer = 0, then I could get up to 0.1 sec delay sacrificing quality.

I was able to run example on my Note2 with maximum resolution 320x240 30fps 500kbps.
When I'm trying to run it on Glass, I have 176x144 maximum and "Fail to connect to camera service" error.

I'm curious, could I get more than 176x144 over h.264 or other protocols?
I completely stuck on "Fail to connect to camera service" error.

My code is pretty much the same as here: 
[Google Glass stream video to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223277/google-glass-stream-video-to-server)

except:

in MainActivity:

```
SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setSurfaceView((SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface))
            .setCallback(this)
            .setPreviewOrientation(90)
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(176, 144, 12, 24000));
```

in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Any help or fresh ideas are much appreciated. 
I heard, Mirror API could be used to stream video, Unfortunately didn't investigated that yet.

Comment: I really would not want to stream video on Glass... I was shocked to see how consistently hot the battery would get when I'd be testing out things on it at work.

Answer (score 2):

The following information might be helpful to make decision to go this route (use Glass for streaming):

I played a little with the parameters and was able to get:

```
.setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H263))
.setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(1280, 720, 30, 500000)
```

Unfortunately, image freezes sometimes and Glass gets extremely hot. The quality is unacceptable.
H264 codec has less problems but I couldn't get even 640x480 stream.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem until I connected my Glass to the internet prior to launching the app. Not sure if that is the case for you, but if so give it a try.